# purpose of error injection macro in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I have seen a macro ALLOW_ERROR_INJECTION which is used in SYSCALL_DEFINEx

```
#ifdef CONFIG_FUNCTION_ERROR_INJECTION
/*
 * Whitelist ganerating macro. Specify functions which can be
 * error-injectable using this macro.
 */
#define ALLOW_ERROR_INJECTION(fname, _etype)                            \
static struct error_injection_entry __used                              \
        __attribute__((__section__("_error_injection_whitelist")))      \
        _eil_addr_##fname = {                                           \
                .addr = (unsigned long)fname,                           \
                .etype = EI_ETYPE_##_etype,                             \
        };
#else
#define ALLOW_ERROR_INJECTION(fname, _etype)
#endif
#endif
```

Can anyone provide me enough documentation on this.

What is the use of it. What is whitelist

Comment: I think it's used for testing the kernel. See https://lwn.net/Articles/209257/

Comment: @Barmar that looks like a different error injection framework (different debugfs files). It doesn't look like there's official documentation for this one. This one comes from kprobes. Regarding the whitelist, `lib/error-inject.c` says "Whitelist of symbols that can be overridden for error injection."

Comment: I couldn't find any actual documentation, either, I just assume it's something similar.